# retreiving instagram story for logged in user via instagram omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, instagram

I am building ruby on rails application which uses instagram omniauth for user authentication. How can I pull user story from Instagram API with data about story viewers?

I am using following gems to enable Instagram Omniauth:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-instagram'
gem 'instagram'
```

Answer (score 2):

They're still no way to get User's Stories data with the Instagram Public API, even if you're authenticated.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/), The [media endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self) only returns items of type **Images**, **Videos** and **Carousel**.

Comment: Is there any additional way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The [official Instagram endpoint documentation site](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) is out dated. There are some "hidden" endpoints which could help you, such as:

```
"feed/user/{$userId}/reel_media/" 

"feed/reels_tray/"
```